# How to skip gestures for topmost view - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I added a `UIImageView` as a subview to my `UIView` and then I added a transparent `UIView` to my view.

Now, the transparent view is the topmost view. But i would like to use Pan, Pinch, rotate gesture on my uiimageView.

The transparent view will have some text message to the user or some grid line to indicate the user to perform some tasks like image rotation, shrink and move etc..

For now, the transparent view is blocking all my gestures.

How can we make the gestures recognized by the `UIImageView` by overriding the topmost `UIView` gesture recogniser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[yourView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` - this way all touch events on that view will be ignored and the next one in the view hierarchy will respond to them.